# How do I make gdalwarp set target extents to -180 -90 180 90?

Tags: gdalwarp

I'm using gdalwarp with the -te option and it doesn't appear to be working like I expected.

I'm running a command like:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -te -180 -90 180 90 -tr 0.1 0.1 -t_srs EPSG:4326 input.tif output.tif
```

or

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -te -180.0 -90.0 180.0 90.0 -tr 0.1 0.1 -t_srs EPSG:4326 input.tif output.tif
```

But when I run gdalinfo after executing gdalwarp I get this:

```
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0'0.00"W, 90d 0'0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -89.9903092) (180d 0'0.00"W, 89d59'25.11"S)
Upper Right ( 179.9806183,  90.0000000) (179d58'50.23"E, 90d 0'0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 179.9806183, -89.9903092) (179d58'50.23"E, 89d59'25.11"S)
Center      (  -0.0096908,   0.0048454) (  0d 0'34.89"W,  0d 0'17.44"N)
```

How can I create a geotiff where the extents with the following values?

```
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0'0.00"W, 90d 0'0.00"N)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0'0.00"W, 90d 0'0.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  90.0000000) (180d 0'0.00"E, 90d 0'0.00"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000) (180d 0'0.00"E, 90d 0'0.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) (  0d 0'0.00"W,  0d 0'0.00"N)
```

Comment: I was able to force the extents to the desired values by running a second gdalwarp command with `-te` and no other options. `gdalwarp -te -180 -90 180 90 output.tif correctExtents.tif`.  I still think I should be able to do this in one command though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify the -ts option rather than the -tr option. In other words, you know the exact size of your output array, so specify it rather than let GDAL calculate it. Otherwise, gdalwarp tries to calculate it (note sure where this is in the codebase, but see [this](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/alg/gdaltransformer.cpp#L291).

Comment: So are you saying using "-tr" makes the -"te" not strictly enforced?

Comment: I had the same problem some time ago, and it appeared to be a rounding error (some conditional testing on something that was being rounded off). I just got around it by specifying the actual size of the array. Not sure whether this still applies to current versions of the library tho'